# Don't include comma while writing to CSV in Django?

Tags: python, django, csv

I am writing like this in Django:

```
writer.writerow(['VideoName ', 'Director ', 'Cameraman ', 'Editor ', 'Reporter ', 'Tag '])
```

It is writing in CSV like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'

Video, Director, Cameraman
```

But I only want:

```
Video Director Cameraman
```

I am doing this in Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `delimiter` when you are initializing your `csv.writer`:

```
writer = csv.writer(buffer, delimiter=" ")
```

Comment: Did that,  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; delimiter=" "; filename="report.csv"'

but it shows the comma.

Comment: Nope, you should set the delimiter in the `csv.writer` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Specify [delimiter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv#csv.Dialect.delimiter) when create csv.writer.

In addition to that trim field values. (`'videoName '` -> `'videoName'`)

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=' ')
>>> writer.writerow(['VideoName', 'Director', 'Cameraman', 'Editor', 'Reporter', 'Tag'])
VideoName Director Cameraman Editor Reporter Tag
```

Comment: I did that, but still I get the comma.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you don't want CSV format in your rows ?

You can writerow `"".join(['VideoName ', 'Director ', 'Cameraman ', 'Editor ', 'Reporter ', 'Tag '])`, it will write the `VideoName Director Cameraman Editor Reporter Tag` string as a line of you CSV file.

Or you can remove the spaces from your array entries, and specify the space character as CSV separator.